# Get the node path of selected text by the user with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, path

I'm trying to build the following:
Let's say that a user selects 'List Two' to copy it, how do I get the path to that node in javascript?
Example of node if 'List Two' selected: `//HTML/BODY/DIV/UL/LI[1]`
My files
index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TheWeb</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:#e9e9e9; color:#777;">
        <div>
            <ul id="list">
                <li>List One</li>
                <li>List Two</li>
                <li>List Three</li>
                <li id="four">List Four</li>
            </ul>
            <hr />
            <div>
                <p id="p">Just a Paragraph</p> <i>xdd</i>
                <hr />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the javascript.js I'm currently using that I copy from somewhere that I can't find anymore:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getElementPath(element)
    {
        return "//" + $(element).parents().andSelf().map(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var tagName = this.nodeName;
            if ($this.siblings(tagName).length > 0) {
                tagName += "[" + $this.prevAll(tagName).length + "]";
            }
            return tagName;
        }).get().join("/").toUpperCase();
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("div, p, a, ul, li, table, td, tr, b, i, span, u").click(function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            window.alert(getElementPath(this));
        });
    });
</script>
```

This also requires jQuery.
That works but it's unstable, and it has bugs. Also, is there a universal like `*` instead of using all the tags independently?

```
$("div, p, a, ul, li, table, td, tr, b, i, span, u").click()
```

Note: I prefer not to use jQuery but if it is to complicated without jQuery well jQuery is fine.
Let me know if you need me to clarify anything/something to you. Thanks.

**EDIT**, adding more info:
The answers I've got are amazing but I have encounter more obstacles. Let's say a user selects 'List One' and 'List Two' at the same time, (those are two different paths) how would I get two different paths in one select/shot?
By select I mean selecting text from the website with you pointer (highlighting), do not confuse it with a click.
Thanks again, very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery it is pretty easy...

```
//click handler for the entire document
$(document).click(function (e) {
    //find the path from the current element to the html element
    var path = $(e.target).parents().addBack().map(function () {
        //find siblings of same type
        var siblings = $(this).siblings(this.tagName);
        //don't add the index if there are no siblings of same type
        return this.tagName + (siblings.length ? '[' + $(this).prevAll(this.tagName).length + ']' : '');
    }).get().join('/');
    console.log(path)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/V3ALB/)

---

Using your method

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).click(function (event) {
        console.log(getElementPath(event.target));
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JfL87/)

---

Without jQuery

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onclick = function (e) {
    var array = [];
    var el = e.target;
    while (el != document) {
        var sibs = 0,
            sib = el.previousSibling;
        while (sib.previousSibling) {
            if (sib.tagName == el.tagName) {
                sibs++;
            }
            sib = sib.previousSibling;
        }

        array.push(el.tagName + (sibs ? '[' + sibs + ']' : ''));
        el = el.parentNode;
    }
    console.log('//' + array.reverse().join('/'))
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LzKen/)

Comment: This is very interesting, but I have tried the demos and they are working on clicking instead of when selecting text. The reason is to allow multiple selection. What would the solution could be if a user selects multiple text from different nodes at the same time? Example: The user selects 'List One' and 'List Two' at the same time and those are in different nodes, could the output be two paths? One for each? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

with Jquery you can use ["*" selector](http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "*" ).bind( "click", function() {
     window.alert(getElementPath($( this ));
  });
}
```